# PHP multi cURL performance worse than sequential file_get_contents

Tags: php, apache, curl, curl-multi

I am writing an interface in which I must launch 4 http requests to get some infomation.

I implemented the interface in 2 ways:

1. using sequential file_get_contents.
2. using multi curl.

I have benchmarked the 2 versions with jmeter. The result shows that multi curl is much better than sequential file_get_contents when there's only 1 thread in jmeter making requests, but much worse when 100 threads.

The question is: which could bring the bad performance of multi curl?

My multi curl code is as below:

```
$curl_handle_arr = array ();
$master = curl_multi_init();
foreach ( $call_url_arr as $key => $url )
{
    $curl_handle = curl_init( $url );
    $curl_handle_arr [$key] = $curl_handle;
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_POST , true );
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , http_build_query( $params_arr [$key] ) );
    curl_multi_add_handle( $master , $curl_handle );
}
$running = null;
$mrc = null;
do
{
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $master , $running );
}
while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
while ( $running && $mrc == CURLM_OK )
{
    if (curl_multi_select( $master ) != - 1)
    {
        do
        {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $master , $running );
        }
        while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
    }
}
foreach ( $call_url_arr as $key => $url )
{
    $curl_handle = $curl_handle_arr [$key];
    if (curl_error( $curl_handle ) == '')
    {
        $result_str_arr [$key] = curl_multi_getcontent( $curl_handle );
    }
    curl_multi_remove_handle( $master , $curl_handle );
}
curl_multi_close( $master );
```

Comment: 100 threads only for 4 requests ? ... Could you show me your benchmarking code?

Comment: [PR] [mpyw/co](https://github.com/mpyw/co): Asynchronous cURL executor simply based on resource and Generator.

Comment: @mpyw, sorry for my poor English. What I meant is: I wrote an interface and in the interface 4 http requests must be made to get some data, then the interface processes the data. I used jmeter to benchemark the 2 versions. The performance of the multi curl version is rather bad when I set the thread number to 100 in jmeter.

Answer (score 6):

## 1. Simple optimization

- You should sleep about 2500 microseconds if `curl_multi_select` failed.
  Actually, **it defintely fails** sometimes for each execution.
  Without sleeping, **your CPU resources get occupied by lots of `while (true) { }` loops**.
- If you do nothing after **some** (not all) of the requests have finished,
  you should let maximum timeout seconds larger.
- Your code is written for old libcurls. As of libcurl version 7.2,
  the state `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` does not appear anymore.

So, the following code

```
$running = null;
$mrc = null;
do
{
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $master , $running );
}
while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
while ( $running && $mrc == CURLM_OK )
{
    if (curl_multi_select( $master ) != - 1)
    {
        do
        {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $master , $running );
        }
        while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
    }
}
```

should be

```
curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
do
{
    if (curl_multi_select($master, 99) === -1)
    {
        usleep(2500);
        continue;
    }
    curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
} while ($running);
```

### Note

The timeout value of `curl_multi_select` should be tuned only if you want to do something like...

```
curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
do
{
    if (curl_multi_select($master, $TIMEOUT) === -1)
    {
        usleep(2500);
        continue;
    }
    curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
    while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($master))
    {
        /* Do something with $info */
    }
} while ($running);
```

Otherwise, the value should be extreamly large.
(However, `PHP_INT_MAX` is too large; libcurl treats it as an invalid value.)

## 2. Easy experiment in one PHP process

I tested using my parallel cURL executor library: [mpyw/co](https://github.com/mpyw/co)

(The prep. `for` is improper and it should be `by`, sorry for my poor English xD)

```
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use mpyw\Co\Co;

function four_sequencial_requests_for_one_hundread_people()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
        $tasks[] = function () use ($i) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, [
                CURLOPT_URL => 'example.com',
                CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            ]);
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; ++$j) {
                yield $ch;
            }
        };
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    yield $tasks;
    $end = microtime(true);
    printf("Time of %s: %.2f sec\n", __FUNCTION__, $end - $start);
}

function requests_for_four_hundreds_people()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 400; ++$i) {
        $tasks[] = function () use ($i) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, [
                CURLOPT_URL => 'example.com',
                CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            ]);
            yield $ch;
        };
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    yield $tasks;
    $end = microtime(true);
    printf("Time of %s: %.2f sec\n", __FUNCTION__, $end - $start);
}

Co::wait(four_sequencial_requests_for_one_hundread_people(), [
    'concurrency' => 0, // Zero means unlimited
]);

Co::wait(requests_for_four_hundreds_people(), [
    'concurrency' => 0, // Zero means unlimited
]);
```

I tried for five times to get the following results:

[image]

I also tried in reverse order (The 3rd request was kicked xD):

[image]

These results represent **too many concurrent TCP connections actually decrease throughputs**.

## 3. Advanced optimization

### 3-A. For different destinations

If you want to optimize for both few and many concurrent requests, the following dirty solution may help you.

1. Share the number of requesters using `apcu_add` / `apcu_fetch` / `apcu_delete`.
2. Switch methods(sequencial or parallel) by current value.

### 3-B. For the same destinations

`CURLMOPT_PIPELINING` will help you. **This option bundles all HTTP/1.1 connections for the same destination into one TCP connection.**

```
curl_multi_setopt($master, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try it out later.

Comment: If the timeout values of the 4 http requests are set to 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s respectively using curl_setopt function, then what is the proper value of the timeout of curl_multi_select?

Comment: I have tried your code but the result is as same as before.

Comment: I also tested in another way.

Comment: It seems that curl multi is inadequate in high concurrency situations. I will try other solutions and keep you informed. Many thanks again for your help!